# Expressionengine prev next display only 1 category

Tags: conditional-statements, preview, expressionengine

First of all sorry for my explanations, my tech english is not perfect

Well I have a channel named “blog” connect to different categories inside a group category.

I use an unique template for displaying all entries of all categories, i call it : “article”

Inside the article template, I want to display “preview” and “next” links to navigate through each entry of only one category (ID = 13)

with this code (example with the preview link) it’s working and when i visit a entry belong to the category 13 i see my links and able to navigate

`{exp:channel:prev_entry category=“13” }   /expressionengine/themes/site_themes/agile_records/images/arrownavleft.png  {/exp:channel:prev_entry}`

But my problem begin now, this links are also visible in all categories entries i don’t know how hiding these links (preview and next) in the article template for them! the code above is not enough, I try some conditionals with no success

Sorry I am maybe not clear but hard to explain in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your Prev/Next Entry tag in a conditional so it only displays on entries for category 13.

I'd use [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs) for this.

```
{if segment_1_category_id == 13}
  {exp:channel:prev_entry category=“13” }
   ....
  {/exp:channel:prev_entry}
{/if}
```

You'll need to set the segment_n_category_id to match the URL segment of your category.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i knew it need conditional but i didn't know the good one ;-)